# How does the answer to Feynman's Restaurant Problem change if $M$ is not restricted to a single value?

Tags: probability

First, the background: [Feynman's restaurant problem](http://www.feynmanlectures.info/exercises/Feynmans_restaurant_problem.html) asks how we can maximise the total rating of the meals we eat at a restaurant with $N$ items on the menu, *given that we know up-front that we are going to eat $M$ meals there*.

I have transcribed the problem and answer:

> Assume that a restaurant has $N$ dishes on its menu that are rated
>   from worst to best, $1$ to $N$ (according to your personal
>   preferences). You, however, don't know the ratings of the dishes, and
>   when you try a new dish, all you learn is whether it is the best
>   (highest rated) dish you have tried so far, or not. Each time you eat
>   a meal at the restaurant you either order a new dish or you order the
>   best dish you have tried so far. Your goal is to maximize the average
>   total ratings of the dishes you eat in $M$ meals (where $M \leq N$).
>
> The average total ratings in a sequence of meals that includes $n$
>   "new" dishes and $b$ "best so far" dishes can be no higher than the
>   average total ratings in the sequence having all $n$ "new" dishes
>   followed by all $b$ "best so far" dishes. Thus a successful strategy
>   requires you to order some number of new dishes and thereafter only
>   order the best dish so far. The problem then reduces to the following:
>
> Given $N$ (dishes on the menu) and $M\leq N$ (meals to be eaten at
>   the restaurant), how many new dishes $D$ should you try before
>   switching to ordering the best of them for all the remaining $(M–D)$
>   meals, in order to maximize the average total ratings of the dishes
>   consumed?
>
> Answer : $D = \sqrt{2(M+1)} - 1$

So if we are visiting a restaurant with $20$ dishes $7$ times, we should pick different dishes for the first $3$ trips, then have the best of those the next $4$ times.

However, as far as practical application goes, this answer is the answer to a question that doesn't match reality - rarely do we know *exactly* how many times we're going to eat at a restaurant!

Suppose instead of having $M$ equal some fixed value, we instead have $M$ distributed according to some **probability distribution** $P$. For example, suppose we know we are going to visit a restaurant with $20$ dishes on some number of occasions uniformly distributed over $5..10$. What now should be our value for $D$? What about if $P$ is a less simple distribution?

*** edit to add ***

Is it as simple as $\sum_m{P(m) D(m)}$ (which is I think $E(D)$?) where $D(m) = \sqrt{2(m+1)} - 1$ as above? Assuming that $P$ can't change over the course of the exercise, which [as mjqxxxx points out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296302/how-does-the-answer-to-feynmans-restaurant-problem-change-if-m-is-not-restric#comment644392_296302) would be quite possible in reality...

Comment: Sounds like figuring out the ideal will be much more work than the expected increase in happiness the optimal choice will lead you to. Just decide to order the chocolate ice cream each time and spend your mental effort on something more productive instead.

Comment: I imagine the probability distribution $f$ would depend strongly on the quality of the dishes tried so far...

Comment: @HenningMakholm "More productive"...typical corporative mentality. We mathematicians usually increase our "stock" of happiness thinking about such "non-productive" matters, and from time to time someone discovers that these "useless" digressions can be [quite useful](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/116627/useless-math-that-became-useful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this problem up (and its solution), so I guess I should answer the question, "Is it as simple as...". Yes, it's that simple, because (when n and m are unequal) eating exactly n meals and eating exactly m meals are independent events.

Please note, however, that this problem was based on a description of Feynman’s original that turned out to be inaccurate. In Feynman's version meals are rated on a continuum in the range [0,1], rather than being ranked 1 thru N, and the information available to the diner each night includes the rating P of the best meal tried so far, the number of nights n remaining to dine, and a threshold value Pn (that depends only on n) such that if P>Pn the diner repeats the meal rated P (“the best so far”), or otherwise s/he tries something new. Feynman found that to maximize the sum of the diner's meal ratings one should choose Pn = Sqrt[n]/(1+Sqrt[n]). For more detailed information see [this page](http://www.feynmanlectures.info/other/Feynmans_Restaurant_Problem_Revealed.html).

Michael A. Gottlieb

Editor, The Feynman Lectures on Physics New Millennium Edition